# How can I start a cpp bin at every reboot?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, services, startup

I am beginner in LINUX operating system and my question is the next one:

I have a compiled bin from a C++ source code that uses OpenCV and another libs and it displays on the screen the images provided from a USB camera. My code works fine, the next step is to execute this bin file every time when my board have been powered on.
I made some research and I found out the reliable method that can help me is to create my own service that can be enabled using systemctl. I tried it but without success but I'm not sure if my service file has been configured properly. Also, I tried with Startup Applications, again it failed.
PS: my board: Nvidia Jetson Tx2, my OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I am waiting for any advice and appreciate your effort to respond.
Thank you!

Edit:
My service file configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script that will execute my bin
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/nvidia/Desktop/daemonScripts/daemonVDM.sh start
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `daemonVDM.sh`

```
#!usr/bin/bash
path_vdm_bin="/home/nvidia/Desktop/running"
cd $path_vdm_bin
./vdm --camera-sources 1
```

Output `systemctl status myscript`

```
myscript.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
myscript.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

My shell daemonVDM.sh works fine

I executed the next commands:

```
sudo chmod 777 myscript.service
systemctl start myscript
systemctl enable myscript
```

Comment: *" I tried it but without success but I'm not sure if my service file have been configured properly."* Use `journalctl` to find out why it doesn't work. Without logs there's little people here can help you with.

Comment: "the next step is to execute this bin file every time when my board have been powered on" : you could use an After: directive in your service file, to specify the board availability as a condition for your code to run. Regarding your issue, please provide the service file you wrote for further help.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This is the configuration of service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script that will execute my bin

[Service]

ExecStart=/home/nvidia/Desktop/daemonScripts/daemonVDM.sh
Environment="DISPLAY=:1"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"
RestartSec=30
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong

```
#!usr/bin/bash
```

Please try

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Actually let's simplify it further:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/nvidia/Desktop/running && ./vdm --camera-sources 1
```

Now the `vdm` app will only run if the script has been able to enter the destination directory and will exit otherwise.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/nvidia/Desktop/daemonScripts/daemonVDM.sh start
```

`start` is unnecessary though it will do no harm. You can simply remove it. Your bash script doesn't handle any command line arguments at all.

Comment: I heard my camera turn on but it failed for some reason, my output of systemctl status myscript is the following: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused, cannot open display, myscript.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status = 134/n/a, Failed with result 'exit-code'

Comment: In your service, you have `WantedBy=multi-user.target`. I am not familiar with your board and I don't know if and how you run XWindows, but `multi-user.target` is text console. Therefore, your application complains that there is no display to open. You have to run Xwindows, so your application will have a display where it can open a window and show its content. With that in mind, you probably have to enable automatic login in XWindows to start session for your app. Then you can start your app. You can do it with a service or put it in startup applications list in your Xwindows session.

Comment: @Fredi perhaps you need to specify your User/Group for this unit. Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot